# Trying to extract number between 2 characters '|' MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have column and need to extract number between 2 pipes `|`, example data inside is `AAA|12345678|#RRR`. I need to get this number `12345678`.

my code is:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(column_name,CHARINDEX('|',column_name) + 1, CHARINDEX('|',column_name) - CHARINDEX('|',column_name) - 1)
FROM [name].[name].[table_name]
```

Comment: Please include the sql server version you are using (2017, 2016, 2015, 2012R2, 2012, etc). See also [How to determine the version, edition, and update level of SQL Server and its components](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/321185/how-to-determine-the-version-edition-and-update-level-of-sql-server-an)

Comment: What's wrong with your current code?   What is your question, exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your own code:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(column_name,CHARINDEX('|',column_name) + 1, 
CHARINDEX('|',column_name) - CHARINDEX('|',column_name) - 1)
FROM [name].[name].[table_name]
```

The second part of substring is not correct. It should be:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(column_name,CHARINDEX('|',column_name) + 1, 
CHARINDEX('|',column_name, CHARINDEX('|',column_name)))
FROM [name].[name].[table_name]
```

The nested CHARINDEX will look for the position of the second pipe. and the SUBSTRING will start from the first pipe and continue to the second

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the 2nd position, you can use a little `XML` or `ParseName()`

**XML Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,column_name varchar(max))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'AAA|12345678|#RRR')


Select ID
      ,SomeValue = Cast('<x>' + replace(column_name,'|','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).value('/x[2]','varchar(max)')
 From @YourTable
```

**ParseName() Example**

```
Select ID
      ,SomeValue = parsename(replace(column_name,'|','.'),2)
 From @YourTable
```

**Both would Return**

```
ID  SomeValue
1   12345678
```

Comment: Thank you so much! ParseName works great, simple and effective, txt a lot.

Comment: @DKCroat Happy to help.  Just a word of caution with ParseName() ... any extra periods in the string return unexpected results.

Answer (score 0):

String extraction is generally tricky in SQL Server.  But if you only have one numeric value and are looking for it, then the code isn't that bad:

```
select patindex('%[0-9]|%', str),
       substring(str, patindex('%|[0-9]%', str), patindex('%[0-9]|%', str) - patindex('%|[0-9]%', str) + 1)
from (values ('AAA|12345678|#RRR')) v(str)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use [`PARSENAME()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/parsename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) :

```
select parsename(replace(str, '|', '.'), 2)
from ( values ('AAA|12345678|#RRR')
     ) v(str);
```