# Extract a value between 2 pipes

Tags: sql-server

My column has values

```
1234|aaa4|8752
```

The length of these values are not fixed.

I want to extract the second value `aaa4`

I tried writing this

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(column_name,CHARINDEX('|',column_name) + 1, 
CHARINDEX('|',column_name, CHARINDEX('|',column_name)))
FROM [name].[name].[table_name]
```

With this reference

[Trying to extract number between 2 characters '|' MS SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52097806/trying-to-extract-number-between-2-characters-ms-sql)

But this is not working fine and it is showing text after the second pipe as well

`aaa4|8752`

It is because we are using substring and the third argument is of the length. So it is taking other characters as well. How do i limit the length to the second pipe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(
    column_name,
    CHARINDEX('|', column_name) + 1,
    CHARINDEX('|', column_name, CHARINDEX('|', column_name) + 1) - CHARINDEX('|', column_name) - 1
) AS extracted_value
FROM [name].[name].[table_name];
```

- `CHARINDEX('|', column_name)` finds the position of the first pipe.
- `CHARINDEX('|', column_name, CHARINDEX('|', column_name) + 1)` finds
  the position of the second pipe, starting the search after the first
  pipe.
- The difference between the positions of the second pipe and the first
  pipe (- 1) gives you the length of the substring you want to extract.